# Opening a csv file server side (heroku) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, heroku

I have a local dev Rails environment in which I have this code in my controller:

```
  def csv_to_array(file)
    @comment_array = []
    CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true) do |column|
      @comment_array << column['Phrase']
    end
    @comment_array
  end

csv_to_array('../hub/data/comment_file.csv')
```

This works fine in my local environment. It opens the csv file, and parses it into an array. The root rails directory here is `hub`.

However - When I push this app to heroku and try to run the same code server side, it errors out because it can't locate the file. How can I open a csv file server side? Did just the location change, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you add the file into the *git* repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your local environment, you're running the Ruby process from the Rails root directory. This is why you're able to locate the file using `'../hub/data/comment_file.csv'` (or probably just `'./data/comment_file.csv'`

However, Heroku and many other hosts will run it from other locations.

You'll have to specify the full path of the file:

```
File.join(Rails.root, 'data/comment_file.csv')
```